# UIButton is getting stretched with Auto Layout

Tags: ios, ios7, autolayout

I am doing one app in Xcode 5 and also using auto layout, 
the initial layout is quite simple, a table view, textfield and a button with .png as backgrond.

When I test on 4" inch device all is good, 
but when i test on 3.5 the button is getting oval shape.

The tableView has a preset constrain for Height and Width and all other objects have the basic constraints added. If I try to add height/width for UIButton I get several warnings. 
Here is the screenshot and constrains for UIButton

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is you are basing the size of your button off the size of the view (top and bottom space).

Instead, try creating a series of constraints that look more like this:

```
Top Space to : Table View
Equals: 150

Horizontally Center Button in View

Button Height
Equals: 75

Button Width
Equals: 100
```

This set of constraints will make a button with a set size (100, 75) that is centered horizontally in your view and placed below your table view with a spacing of 150 pixels.

Answer (score 3):

If  do you use storyboard, is very simple.

Try this.

Fisrt clear all contains.
After click the button, and click follow my image.

[image]

The Xcode create all constraints for you.
This work for me.